# WCF REST url prefix attribute

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, asp.net-web-api, wcf-rest

I am developing WCF REST services. I have a contract:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IContract
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "GET",
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        UriTemplate = "/somemethod/{param1}")]
    SomeResult SomeMethod(int param1) { ... }

    /*

    More methods...

    */
}
```

Is there a way to configure a common url prefix for all the methods of a given contract. Maybe something like in Web API `[RoutePrefix("...")]` attribute?

Comment: What do you mean by Common Url prefix ?

Comment: @Tommassiov Like for instance I want all my urls to start from "/users/".

Answer (score 0):

To be honest I'm not sure if it's possible but maybe deriving your own attribute from WebInvoke could help? You could then internally add your prefix to whatever content of UriTemplate will be set.

But I never tried it so...

Answer (score -1):

Try like this-

```
UriTemplate = "/users/somemethod/{param1}"
```